# 32 bit Linux assemble code

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I have a couple of questions about assembly code

1. What is the difference between `mov` and `mov1`?
2. Can you explain this output to me?

---

```
 804879a:  -    push   %ebp    
 804879b:       mov    %esp,%ebp    
 804879d:       sub    $0x14,%esp       <-allocating space for local variables in heap     
 80487a0:       mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax    
 80487a3:       mov    %al,-0x14(%ebp)    
 80487a6:       movl   $0x79,-0xc(%ebp)    
 80487ad:       movl   $0x5,-0x8(%ebp)    
 80487b4:       movl   $0xc,-0x4(%ebp)    
 80487bb:       mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax    
 80487be:       mov    -0xc(%ebp),%edx    
 80487c1:       add    %edx,%eax              <- adding edx to eax     
 80487c3:       mov    %eax,%edx    
 80487c5:       sub    -0x4(%ebp),%edx    
 80487c8:       movsbl -0x14(%ebp),%eax    
 80487cc:       cmp    %eax,%edx    
 80487ce:       sete   %al    
 80487d1:       movzbl %al,%eax    
 80487d4:       leave    
 80487d5:       ret    
   ^    
   |    
(memory addresses)
```

I understand the the first couple of lines is for allocating memory for the local variables.

What I mostly do not understand are the `$0x79` numbers. What are they?

Also if some can explain to me what `sete` is that would be great

Comment: It's `movl`, not `mov1`.

Comment: I think you mean `x86` Linux.  There are LOTS more 32-bit architectures around, notably including ARM.

Comment: An instruction starts with a *mnemonic*. To understand what `sete` instruction is a simple google will help

Answer (score 1):

This is ATT or similar syntax (as opposed to Intel syntax). "$" means immediate value (for Intel syntax, "$" means current location, so a loop to itself would be | loop $ | ). movl means long (32 bits) and the suffix is needed if neither operand implies an operand size as opposed to a register name (al = 8 bits, ax = 16 bits, eax = 32 bits, rax = 64 bits). SETE sets AL to 1 if the current condition code means "equal" (set by the previous cmp instruction), otherwise it sets AL to zero. movsbl moves an extended signed 8 bit value to a 32 bit operand.